# Correct use of case (error with then)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone understand why I am getting this error for the below line of code? Please let me know!

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

Slight modification of this post: How do I add hyphens to this line of code? For instance the format I am getting is PTEE032981. How do I get PT-EE-032981?

Please let me know if this can be answered in this post.

```
case when (MU.Number like '%co-load%' then SUBSTRING(UPPER(REPLACE(Mu.Number,'-','')) ,
 PATINDEX('%[nw]t[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UPPER(REPLACE(Mu.Number,'-',''))),10)) 
 else ME.MovementReference end as [MovementReference],
```

Comment: MySQL or sql-server ? which db ?

Comment: @Prabhat G Sql server

Comment: `when (` remove the `(`

Comment: Why is your `then` in paretheses?

Comment: Silly mistake! thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a starting parenthesis:

```
case 
    when MU.Number like '%co-load%' 
        then SUBSTRING(UPPER(REPLACE(Mu.Number, '-', '')), PATINDEX('%[nw]t[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', UPPER(REPLACE(Mu.Number, '-', ''))), 10) 
    else ME.MovementReference 
end as [MovementReference],
```

Comment: @RaduGherghiu no worries (it says I need to accept this as an answer in 2 minutes) Meanwhile, I am dealing with this issue as I can't add hyphens to the code. I have slightly modified the brief of the post. Any ideas?

Comment: @Diana Ideally this would be a different question, but adding hyphens could be done with concatenation. But for your example `PTEE032981`, you would need to know at what position to insert the hyphens. It would be something like `SUBSTRING(Number, 0, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Number, 2, LEN(Number))` etc. You need to extend this for your case. I hope it's helpful